# E: Unable to locate package git - Ubuntu on EC2

Tags: git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, packaging, apt

Looks to me like there may be a problem with the Ubuntu EC2 mirrors.  After a fresh apt-get update, I'm seeting this:

```
$ apt-get install -yq git
E: Unable to locate package git
```

After a few more `apt-get`'s, it will often succeed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mirrors still seem to be broken, but I was able to work around the issue with a dumb loop:

```
# stupid loop to get around ubuntu package mirror problems
for attempt in 1 2 3; do
  if [ ! -z "`which git`" ]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "Trying to install git, attempt $attempt"
  sudo apt-get update -yq --fix-missing
  sudo apt-get install -yq git
done
```

3 attempts is usually enough to find a working mirror.

Comment: I would've expected the mirrors to be fixed by now.  Glad this still helps though!

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have set 5 atempts and each time I get :
    Reading package lists...
    Reading package lists...
    Building dependency tree...
    Reading state information...
    E: Unable to locate package git...
Please help me !

Answer (score 28):

Update `apt-get` packages, run the following command:

```
$ apt-get update
```

Comment: Not sure you understood the question.  The issue is that `apt-get update` returns different results due to upstream mirrors being broken.

Comment: My bad then, it is just that I have faced the same issue which got resolved by only a simple `$ apt-get update`

Comment: I had `E: Unable to locate package  xyz` error which was solved by this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.  Below one worked for me.

```
sudo apt install amazon-ec2-utils
```